# Need to translate a Rotation Matrix to Rotation y, x, z OpenGL & Jitter for 3D Game

Tags: physics, matrix, rotation, .net

I am using the Jitter Physics engine which gives a rotation matrix:

```
M11 M12 M13
M21 M22 M23
M21 M32 M33
```

And I need it so OpenGL can use it for rotation

```
GL.Rotate(xr, 1, 0, 0)
GL.Rotate(yr, 0, 1, 0)
GL.Rotate(zr, 0, 0, 1)
```

Initially I Tried

```
xr = M11
yr = M22
zr = M33

[1 0 0]
[0 1 0]
[0 0 1]
```

Which did not work, please help, I have been struggling on this for days :(

**Re-Edit**

*The blocks are stored in text files with Euler angles so it needs to be converted or the rendering engine will simply fail.*

I am now using the matrix in the text files.

Example Block

```
1,1,1                      'Size
0,0,0                      'Position
255,255,255                'Colour
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0          'Rotation Matrix
```

Comment: I suspect you need the math to convert a rotation matrix to Euler angles. Euler angles are a set of three angles applied one after the other, and the order you apply them matters, so the conversion from a rotation matrix to Euler angles is different depending on the ordering (there may be a standard order, I forget). Also, a matrix contains too much information (it may specify translation, scaling and skew as well as rotation). You can symbolically apply the rotations in order to a unit matrix to derive a rotation matrix - a sensible inverse shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: That said, I find it hard to believe OpenGL can't accept a transform matrix directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing that is possible, though I imagine insanely difficult, and since there is a better way, unnecessary.
I'm also assuming that your using OpenGL 2.1, since glRotate was deprecated in OpenGL 3.x.

So, Using OpenGL 2.1, instead of reversing the matrix from your physics API, I suggest you just plug that matrix straight into OpenGL. This can be done with `glLoadMatrix`. Using that function, whatever matrix you input will be the matrix used to transform your model. That is, any translations, rotations, and scaling transforms will be used.

- [glMatrixMode](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)
- [glLoadIdentity](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml)
- [glLoadMatrix](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glLoadMatrix.xml)

For Example:

```
float PhysicsTransformMatrix[16];

// code to get your matrix loaded into PhysicsTransformMatrix

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

while(gameIsRunning)
{
    // prep stuff...

    glPushMatrix();
        // takes the place of the usual `glRotate`, `glTranslate`, and `glScale` calls
        glLoadMatrix(PhysicsTransformMatrix);

        // rendering stuff...
    glPopMatrix(); // you could use `glLoadIdentity()` instead of glPush/glPop
                   // but there is a noteable difference.
}
```

**Edit:** Found a PDF document detailing how to find the possible solutions. The document has a lot of math. Though if your familiar with Matrices, and have gone through Trig, it shouldn't be too hard. It seems to have a problem with large parenthesis, I'm not sure it that's a problem with the document or the viewer.

- [Rotation Matrix To Euler.pdf](https://truesculpt.googlecode.com/hg-history/38000e9dfece971460473d5788c235fbbe82f31b/Doc/rotation_matrix_to_euler.pdf) - 7 pages
- [Rotation about an arbitrary axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721544/circular-rotation-around-an-arbitrary-axis) - StackOverflow Question

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, since I already use a pop and push matrix function this would be easy to put in the code but now I need a method for turning the rotation into a matrix as well for reading the information of certain parts of the world.

Comment: You are welcome. Made an edit that might be help-full.

Comment: Hmm, actually for another part in the game I really need to transform Euler to Matrix, I'm also still is secondary/high school so I haven't gone through Trigonometry yet, I only have basic knowledge of sine and cosine

Comment: Hmmm, that's going to make thing's tricky. Your probably going to need either a library, or to expand upon that knowledge. sin/cos/tan/arctan, vectors, and matrices. The better your grasp of those, the less you'll need a library. Google is going to be your best friend here, unless you want to spend some money. And I added another link. Those two should encompass whatever you might want to do with rotations.

Comment: I'll look into libraries, as my basic understanding has proven to be insufficient right now, I don't want too look into paid solutions as I am trying to do this on a budget of £10 max, which is proving difficult.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHLmeuyNEIU&feature=youtu.be This is the problem I am facing :/ the positions are accurate but rendering the angles is a catastrophy because the blocks are stored in euler angles

Comment: Do you think you could render another wire-frame box to show the collision box? Like the little wire-frame boxes here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YM9lzgIp0M

Comment: Sure, agh just thought lost my account as i didn't note down the username XD but you can log in with opedid

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gcqFjXE7TQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I don't know :/  Maybe it need's sweep collision tests? I notice your collision box stays exactly with the cube, you might try recalculating the box every frame or two, so that rotations don't effect the physics box, like in my link. His rendered-boxes rotate all around, and the physics box just get's taller, longer, wider, etc.  You might then keep a second box like the one you have for more detailed collisions.